# Upgraded to TypeScript 3.5 caused imported namespace to fail finding Enum at runtime

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces

I've managed to upgrade an older Angular.js application from Typescript 2.7 to 3.5 and it managed to compile successfully with `tsc.exe`.
When running the application, at certain parts of the code one gets the following kind of error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'EnumLiteral1' of undefined

So let's say I have an Enum in Typescript (not using `const` in the declaration) that looks like this:

```js
namespace App.Contracts {

    export enum MyEnum {
        EnumLiteral1,
        EnumLiteral2,
    ...
    }

}
```

When I have code that needs to make use of this Enum, I used to have this import that used to work with Typescript 2.7:

```js
import MyEnum = App.Contracts.MyEnum;
```

And the usage was just a normal Enum statement: `MyEnum.EnumLiteral1`.

So when I compile this in 2.7, it works just fine but in 3.5 its as if it tries to access `MyEnum` like a class instance that is `undefined`. 
Looking at the generated Javascript reveals only that with the 2.7 compiler, the Enum code is generated before the code using the Enum while in 3.5 it generates it after the code using the Enum.

I have tried specifying the fully qualified namespace to access the Enum and it works then. But before I resort to going that direction I first want to figure out what is wrong.

I hope my description is clear enough. Please let me know if it is not so.

My question: Is this a bug or is there something I need to change in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is replace the ‛import =‛ with ‛import from‛, I believe import = only [works well in conjunction with require](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

Comment: I looked at your approach but unfortunately trying to perform an import within a namespace gives this error: Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module. So I think those kinds of module referencing is not going to work for my case.